# Java interface naming convention

Tags: java, interface

When we write a java program with multiple classes, we name the java file similar to the name of the class with the `main()` method. But when I write a java program consisting of multiple interfaces only, without any `main()` method within them, then what should be the name of the program? Are there any specific rules of naming that program, or I may assign it any name `xyz.java`?

Comment: please do not shout at people.

Comment: If you didn't get what @JensSchauder meant ! Don't use *caps* while typing a question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `main(String[] args)` method has nothing to do with the naming of the class and it's filename.

In fact, the file containing your code has to be identical with the name of the (top-level) class inside that file.

Answer (score 3):

There are code & naming conventions for everything in Java.

You can find most of them here: [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer not to use a prefix on interfaces:

- The prefix hurts readability.
- Using interfaces in clients is the standard best way to program, so
  interfaces names should be as short and pleasant as possible.
  Implementing classes should be uglier to discourage their use.
- When changing from an abstract class to an interface a coding
  convention with prefix I implies renaming all the occurrences of the 
  class    --- not good!